# Toggle UIView with nice animation

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, uiview, toggle

I'm a newbie in iOS dev and I would make a complicated enough for me so if someone could help me and tell me if I'm on the right track !

I have a `MasterViewController`, in this `MasterViewController` I put two UIViews

```
- topContainerView
- bottomContainerView
```

each of these views occupies half of the screen.

I wish I could hide with a nice animation `topContainerView` and expand the `bottomContainerView` in full size (all the screen), pressing a `UIButton` (toggleButton) and then return to normal by re-pressing the button.

I hope you understand me, I'm French and I do not master English well too;-)

See ya'

```
   -(void)toggleSize:(id)sender {

    if(toggleButton.selected == NO) {
        NSLog(@"top container hidden & bottom container full size");
        toggleButton.selected = YES;

        topContainerView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 244.0);

        [UIView beginAnimations:@"SwitchToView1" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];

        topContainerView.frame = CGRectOffset(topContainerView.frame, 0, -244);

        bottomContainerView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 640.0);

        [UIView commitAnimations];


    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"top container viewed & bottom container normal size");
        toggleButton.selected = NO;

        bottomContainerView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 244.0, 320.0, 216.0);

        [UIView beginAnimations:@"SwitchToView2" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];

        bottomContainerView.frame = CGRectOffset(topContainerView.frame, 0, 488);

        topContainerView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 244.0);

        [UIView commitAnimations];

    }
}
```

Comment: Wait, is your code working? What's the problem here?

Comment: UIView animation is good enough to do that animation which u want

Comment: Yes the code works fine, the animation works fine but I want to know if the technique is good and if this is the right way to do?

And if possible I would like a 3D animation :
It need that "topContainerView" in a first time go back, then bottomContainerView is enlarged in "full-size", and vice versa! Is this possible? if so, a code sample would be helpful!

Comment: I read all the doc, thank you! and I can not find my pleasure! I wanted the animation takes place in two stages: - The first time = "topViewContainer" and sinks into the background (depth)
- The 2nd time = "bottomViewContainer" stretch and fill the screen Please help me, I want to learn, at least give me a hint, an indication!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can read more on animations and transitions [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html).
Also, do check out `UIView`'s `transitionFromView` method in detail . Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes the code works fine, the animation works fine but I want to know if the technique is good and if this is the right way to do?

And if possible I would like a 3D animation :
It need that "topContainerView" in a first time go back, then bottomContainerView is enlarged in "full-size", and vice versa! Is this possible? if so, a code sample would be helpful!

Comment: I haven't done any 3d animations so far. Just check whether any of UIViewAnimationOptions(http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIViewAnimationOptions) parameter in transitionFromView method satisfies you.

Comment: I read all the doc, thank you! and I can not find my pleasure!